# Token Swap From Ethereum Host Network To Different Blockchain

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, remix, contract-design

What is a good way to swap tokens from the Ethereum host network to a different network (i.e. the Tron blockchain)? 
Would the best way to do this be to have a smart contract where ERC20 token holders would have to send their tokens and also declare a Tron wallet address to create a public mapping and an array of public keys belonging to the token holders who executed the mapping? Perhaps those two elements can be iterated over off-chain to distribute tokens on the new network? I'm concerned because I don't know if this is the most optimal approach or if it is possible to read and return the on-chain data of an array with a lot of variables due to gas costs? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The method you described would work. A cost optimization would be to log an event whenever a user sent their tokens to the contract. This would remove the requirement for both an array and a mapping. When attempting to read the data off-chain (for the swap to the other token), you can simply read each event that occurred on that contract. An example would be:

`event Swap(address indexed _from, bytes indexed _to, uint256 indexed _amount)`

The `_to` parameter above would be the address of the user on the new chain.

As a note, I believe this is similar to how the ETH1 to ETH2 transition will work.

---

You can also look at historical examples that have happened and may be applicable to your situation.

[EOS](https://eos.io/) created an ERC20 on Ethereum and swapped it for tokens on the EOS network. To do so, they partnered with exchanges to perform the swap for non-US residents.

If your tokens were not on an exchange, you would have had to register your tokens on the EOS site and then perform a swap based on your registered address, similar to your proposal. More information can be found [here](https://eosauthority.com/blog/how_to_generate_your_EOS_fallback_key_from_ethereum_private_key). This worked by taking snapshot of the network at a given time and using the Ethereum public address as a function of the EOS address. You can read more details [here](https://steemit.com/eos/@eosnewyork/the-eos-mainnet-launch-survival-guide-how-to-avoid-scams).

---

One other example is USDT swaps. USDT lives on a few networks—Ethereum, Omni, and Tron, to name a few. These assets get swapped across chains constantly. This is possible because of its centralization, which is something that may not be possible in your case.

To perform a USDT chain swap, you must first make a deal with the Tether team to work out the specifics. A swap then consists of sending USDT on one chain to the Tether team,  and them subsequently sending you USDT on the other chain.

---

Atomic swaps are yet another option. You can read about them [here](https://blockgeeks.com/guides/atomic-swaps/).

These swaps require a level of coordination and a shared secret between parties but can be thought of (from a top-level) as a simple transfer between chains. It requires a concept of a [Hashed Timelock Contract](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/h/hashed-timelock-contract.asp), but is possible depending on your use case.

Additional information may be found [here](https://medium.com/@DontPanicBurns/ethereum-cross-chain-atomic-swaps-5a91adca4f43).